# Is there a way to optimize this C program in terms of run time

Tags: c, linux, performance, performance-testing

its objective is to print all Fibonacci numbers up to the 93th

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
  unsigned long long first=0,second=1,sum;
  printf("%llu,%llu",first,second);
  unsigned char hops=1;
  while (hops<93) {
    sum=first+second;
    printf(",%llu",sum);
    first=second;
    second=sum;
    hops++;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Is that valid for codereview SE? Certainly not for SO, I think.

Comment: I consider this off-topic for being too broad. "Optimise this for speed" is not a question. Asking about a specific concept for optimisation and maybe a certain detail which blocks the progress, that could be a specific enough question.

Comment: How fast does this need to run anyway? 92 iterations of integer arithmetic aren't going to take very long at all.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage At a guess this is about an "unreasonable requirement", sometimes also referred to as "weird requirement for didactical purposes", i.e. a homework assignment or coding challenge.

Comment: i was just looking for a yes or no, based on theory of course in practice it runs very quick

Comment: The code is pretty good compared to standard implementation where you would call a fibonacci function 93 times and recalculate all the values before.

Comment: @user8062843 But the thing is, this code won't scale at all. Fib(93) is probably the largest Fibonacci number that will fit into a 64-bit unsigned int. If you want something that runs optimally for larger values of `hops`, then you need to completely rewrite the code. So I can't actually see any value in trying to optimize this at all.

Comment: This is a good implementation indeed (in terms of time and space complexity). Not much to optimize here.

Comment: The recursion has been removed from the otherwise-traditional recursive fib-algorithm. This is a simple iterative loop, the stock method for optimizing tail-recursive algorithms. In short, it's already done.

Comment: I guess it would be possible with only one assignment per hop; no guarantee that it would be faster that way however. To verify, only measuring is the right answer.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage yeah that is totally true, it has not good practical uses the objective was just to write the best possible code that does the requested

Comment: @interjay.: I overlooked the series part. I thought it is about nth number.

Comment: @Yunnosch please submit an answer with your idea

Comment: given that the answer is well known it could be replaced by one big printf

Comment: You asked for optimisation. In terms of speed the answer by freestyle cannot be beaten. If you want to discuss specifically an assign-once-per-hop optimisation, then ask a question on exactly that. One of the close-votes on this question for being to broad is mine and I am still of that opinion. Freestyles answer in all its glorious sarcasm is actually supporting my opinion, by answering the question as phrased, without any chance of actually being what you need. Clearly define what you need in a separate question, maybe indicating that "one-assignment" seems what would help, and I will try.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you can. Just print precalculated string of numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("0,1,1,2,3,5,...");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think this i the best answer i will get

Comment: @user8062843 In case it satisfies you needs - yes.

Comment: @user8062843 If you want to get something another then you question isn't correct (you should to generalize your question).

Comment: @giusti Are you happy? :-)

Comment: `void` might be OK for some non-hosted environments. The standard does not forbid it and is leaving to implementation. Of course it won't be portable.

Comment: I doubt this would really make a difference. I suspect this program spends 99.9% of its time just printing output, so even totally eliminating everything but that would make no measurable difference.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Yes you are right. The program will run in IO almost all the time. We can't optimize the IO itself, but only the number of requests for it. But the author can change his task to a task without IO. For example, the creation of an array of Fibonacci numbers. And my point is that his task doesn't depend on anything, so result can be precomputed.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to optimize the whole operation you need to think in terms of space and time complexity. From this point onwards you can think how better these can be.

Now printing the `n` numbers will ofcourse require an iteration which will be of time complexity `O(n)`. Is there any better way to do that? The thing is, if you do it multiple times you can get rid of addition by storing it somewhere. But that won't give you any better asymtotic time complexity improvement - rather you will face a `O(n)` space complexity - which will be an over head if printing is something you do only. (And ofcourse pre-computation have to be done).

So yes this solution is good enough to achieve what you are trying to do.

In case you need to scan some input - then I would ask you to go for getting inputs with `getchar` and then form the number from it (if needed). If you consider this in SPOJ or competitive programming judge server these tend to give better result. (Again time is lesser than that of `scanf` in large number of input cases - 10^7 etc).